# MongoDB best practices for choosing _id field type

Tags: mongodb

I'm about to write a webapp based on Node.js and MongoDB. This webapp will have users stored in a table Users. My question is quite simple: since the username will be unique, is it a good idea to change the _id field type from an ObjectId to a String that would contain the username?

I think it would be more convenient and would somehow reduce the number of requests needed to perform several tasks. Typically if I use the username as an _id, references to a User in other tables will directly give me the username and not an ObjectId that I'd need to convert into an intelligible name before displaying it.

Moreover having two different fields (ObjectId as _id + username) would require two indexes to speed up lookups either on ids or on usernames and would require more space in database.

Last, if I understood correctly the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/), on a sharded environment, MongoDB will only be able to ensure uniqueness of the _id field.

BUT, I may miss things that I'd realize (and deeply regret) later.

Can you please shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to refer to this [**Mongodb string id vs objectid, choose how and why?**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @chridam! What I wonder actually is maybe MongoDB deals with ObjectId, by design, better than with any other object types. If not, I think I'll go for usernames as ids.